# Unable to focus on input field in 3d secure authentication stripe reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

[image: Unable to enter otp in the text field tried with different bank cards]

```
 const payload = await stripe!.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
            card: elements!.getElement(
                CardNumberElement
            ) as StripeCardNumberElement,
        },
  
        

    },
   

    );
```

```
  <DialogContent className='popup-check'>
                <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                    <NFTCheckout
                        {...props}
                        setShowCountDown={setShowCountDown}
                    />
                </Elements>
            </DialogContent>
```

Went through documentation everything is fine only at the time of 3d secure authentication the issue happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue causing by some frame blocking but we are unable to find it after lot of debugging also So we used custom iframe for otp screen

```
  const payload = await stripe!.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
            card: elements!.getElement(
                CardNumberElement
            ) as StripeCardNumberElement,
        },
        return_url:window.location.href

    },
    {handleActions:false}

    );
    
 {otpEnable && <><iframe src={otpScreen} title="3d-secure"   
  style={{ width: "800px", height: "700px", border: " 0" }} 
  scrolling="no" /></>}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Bug report](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js/issues/318):

> I wasn't able to do a reproduction for this one but managed to resolve it by adding `disableAutoFocus`, `disableEnforceFocus` & `disableRestoreFocus` properties to the material UI dialog wrapping the payment element and hijacking the focus event.

Answer (score 1):

The presence of `DialogContent` in your posted code suggests the use of Material-UI's Dialog component.

The Dialog component has an accessibility feature that moves the browser's focus to the modal and adds an event listener to keep it there:

[image]

This is preventing focus on the overlaying iframe that Stripe opens. To prevent this, use the `disableEnforceFocus` property on your containing `Dialog` component:

[image]

This behaviour is documented in the Material-UI docs [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-modal/#focus-trap).

Comment: We had the same problem and setting the underlying Dialog's 'disableEnforceFocus' property to 'true' solved it.

Comment: Passing `true` isn't explicitly necessary. React interprets props without values as boolean flags.

Ref: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-default-to-true

Answer (score 0):

The 3DS authentication pages are developed by different card issuers. I don't think there's a standard way to focus a particular input field in the dialog.

Comment: I am not able to enter otp in input field